# Machine learning on NASDAQ

Tags: equities, statistics, machine-learning, nasdaq

I want to perform an ML analysis on NASDAQ, based on historical fundamentals.

Suppose I want to take a temporal window of 10 year and quarterly data.

I have a question:

I suppose I should know the composition of Nasdaq in the previous years. I mean, its symbols in 2012,2013 and so on.

There is a service, API, or a free source doing this?

What is the common practice?

Thank you
Francesco

Comment: The common practice for obtaining data is to search until you find what you are looking for

Comment: The common practice in answering a question is to provide an intelligent response... or be quit. The  previous answers  don't respond my question.